# Removing escape characters when saving a Path in Properties JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am saving the path of a file as using Properties in Java into a config file.

```
this.adb = adb.getAbsolutePath();
```

---

```
this.prop.setProperty("adb", this.adb);
//save config to project root folder
this.prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config"), null);
```

---

**The contents of config file after saving are:**

```
adb=C\:\\Program Files\\Genymobile\\Genymotion\\tools\\adb.exe
```

How do I save it **without the escape characters** so that it can be easy for a user to modify the path manually without having to type in escape characters.

I also tried to save the config file manually without using escape characters, but the program read the property as:

```
C:Program FilesGenymobileGenymotion oolsadb.exe
```

And the code for reading properties from the config file is:

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config"));
this.adb = prop.getProperty("adb");
```

Comment: In java you can just use '/' instead of '\\'. This also ensures that the path will work on both linux and windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved :)

Comment: And how can i get path with / from a File object?
`adb.getAbsolutePath().replace("\"."/")` ? or is there a standard function for that?

Comment: `this.adb.replace("\\", "/").replace("\\:", ":")` doesnt work. Im getting `adb=C\:/Program Files/Genymobile/Genymotion/tools/adb.exe`. Is this something related to fileoutputstream?

Comment: @MidhunVarghese No, it is something related to `java.util.Properties`. Have you considered consulting the Javadoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[java.util.Properties.store](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) uses backslash to escape special characters (e.g. equal sign in properties keys), so a literal backslash itself will need to be escaped \\. If this behaviour is not what you want, don't use java.util.Properties, roll out your own utility Properties class it should be a simple exercise. If your not sure what an escape character is check this Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

The relevant code in Properties class (saveConvert method)

```
            if (aChar == '\\') {
                outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append('\\');
                continue;
            }
```